# How to create monthly files using ADF?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

My Azure SQL Table contains 6 months' data. I need to split data monthly wise stored into blob storage (Like, Sales_01-01-2021.csv) that file need only Jan month data only.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope  you can accept it as answer This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Leon Yue

Yes I tried 

Here i am using 3 things 

1. Look Up : Look up fetching  distinct mmyyyy values from table  like 01-2021, 02-2021
2.ForEach : It will iterate the values sequential manner
3.Copy activity : Inside foreach activity i am using these one and dynamically i created file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Conditional split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-conditional-split) actives in Data Flow:

- The conditional split transformation routes data rows to different
  streams based on matching conditions. The conditional split
  transformation is similar to a CASE decision structure in a
  programming language. The transformation evaluates expressions, and
  based on the results, directs the data row to the specified stream.

Build the condition can achieve your request. For example:

This is my source dataset, date format is "yyyy-mm-dd":
[image]

I use the condition to split the source to get the data in Mar 2021:
[image]

Then just create the sink for the output.